# SimpleForm label capitalizes my text. How to prevent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem and I have the following code:

```
= f.label f.object.name
```

Where `f` is a simple_form object created via `simple_form_for(...) do |f|`

But if `name` returns something like `SOME WORD` it generates capitalized text: `Some word`.

How to prevent it and generate text as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a similar [ruby-forum topic](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/204161#889083). I tested it and it works in my `simple_form`

Basically you should add a second parameter like this:

```
= f.label :name, f.object.name
= f.input :name
```